# Limit SwiftUI modifier .onMove() to current list only

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have declared two separated lists of items within a List/ForEach as the following:

```swift
List {
    ForEach(model) { item in
        ItemView(item)
            .tag(item.id)
    }
    .onMove(perform: { rows, newIndex in
        model.move(items: rows, destination: newIndex)
    })
}
```

Both lists use a different model, identified by its IDs. Nevertheless, on macOS, I have realized that I can drag items from one list to the other list, despite their different IDs.

Is there any possibility to disable the drop functionality (e.g. via `.onInsert()`) of the other list while dragging? I have already a functionality implemented using `NSItemProviderReading` and `NSItemProviderWriting` to be able to detect when the user has started dragging.

Comment: I read your first line as, you have 2 lists inside another list. Is that correct? or is it 2 separate list?

Comment: There are 2 separate lists

Comment: I assume you are on macos, because on ios-15 and macCatalyst it works well as it is.

Comment: Correct! I forgot to mention it

Answer (score 2):

You could try to ignore the inserts, like in this test code that works for me:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var model1 = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
    @State private var model2 = ["Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(model1, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
                .onMove { (indexSet, index) in
                    model1.move(fromOffsets: indexSet, toOffset: index)
                }
                .onInsert(of: [UTType.text]) { pos,prov in
                    print("\n-----> ignoring insert in model1")
                }
            }
            Divider()
            List {
                ForEach(model2, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
                .onMove { (indexSet, index) in
                    model2.move(fromOffsets: indexSet, toOffset: index)
                }
                .onInsert(of: [UTType.text]) { pos,prov in
                    print("\n-----> ignoring insert in model2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your sample code. That is indeed my current workaround. Nevertheless, the "insert" indicator is still present when dragging from one list to the other, which may confuse users and is simply not a clean solution.